# Dividing excel chart into sections

Tags: excel

I want to create this typ of chart in excel:

[image]

With the vertical gridlines dividing the chart by year, and the labels for each year. The guy who made this chart said he thinks he just drew in the lines and added the labels manually somehow. But can this be done any other way? drawing lines in charts isnt very exact and the only other solutions i've found can't really produce the same result.

Comment: To draw the vertical lines you can add a series for each (turn off the vertical gridlines in the pot area). Foprmatted data labels (on a series with hidden points) could be used for the Year labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data that looks something like:

```
Jan-14  4
Feb-14  30
Mar-14  56
Apr-14  23
May-14  3
Jun-14  62
Jul-14  74
Aug-14  12
Sep-14  3
Oct-14  15
Nov-14  63
Dec-14  74
Jan-15  45
Feb-15  3
Mar-15  4
Apr-15  56
May-15  23
Jun-15  3
Jul-15  62
Aug-15  74
Sep-15  12
Oct-15  3
Nov-15  15
Dec-15  63
Jan-16  74
```

You can select that data and add a new scatter plot style chart. It will, by default, look very similar to the one above. To get vertical lines at the years, you can right-click the x-axis and choose "Format Axis". Click "Fixed" for the "Major Unit" and enter 356 as the number.

[image]

Right click again on the x-axis and choose "Add Major Gridlines". You should get a vertical line for each year.

As for the boxes/labels with the years, you may have to do that manually or get creative with VBA.

Comment: yeah that's pretty much how i solved it! although I only changed the major unit to 12, as in 12 months per year and it did it. thanks!